# New-OktaApp in OktaAPI Module will not error out but only seems to freeze

Tags: powershell, okta, okta-api

I am attempting to use New-OktaApp to make a new okta application. It runs without errors, however once it runs powershell fails to run any further and must be forced closed.

Has anyone experienced this before?

If you have used this in the past can you show me an example of how would got it to run and produce an app?

```
Import-Module "pathtomodule\OktaAPI"
Connect-Okta "MyAPIToken" "MyOrg"

New-OktaApp @{

    name = "name";
    label = "label";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples in the GH site, for example

https://github.com/gabrielsroka/OktaAPI.psm1/blob/master/CallOktaAPI.ps1#L12-L33

```
function Add-SwaApp() {
    $user = Get-OktaUser "me"
    
    # see https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/apps#add-custom-swa-application
    $app = @{
        label = "AAA Test App"
        settings = @{
            signOn = @{loginUrl = "https://aaatest.oktapreview.com"}
        }
        signOnMode = "AUTO_LOGIN"
        visibility = @{autoSubmitToolbar = $false}
    }
    $app = New-OktaApp $app

    # see https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/apps#assign-user-to-application-for-sso
    $appuser = @{id = $user.id; scope = "USER"}
    Add-OktaAppUser $app.id $appuser
}
```